# Vector Identities Question - concerning cross and dot product

Tags: vectors

If $a\cdot b = 0$ and $x+ (x\cdot b)\,a = b$, find the vector $x$.

I don’t know how to approach this question. I understand that $x\cdot b$ will be a scalar - but is it cross producted to $a$? Any hints or a walkthrough with this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For formatting, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Take dot products on both sides with $b$. This allows you to determine the value of $x\cdot b$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Once you have done this, the answer is given by $x=b-(x\cdot b)a$.